# Managing profiles in Powershell 2.0

Tags: scripting, powershell-2.0

as far as I understand, powershell has one profile per user. I would like to prepare multiple environments for different "hats" I could put on my head. Like start my "database worker shell" which provides a set of shortcuts for working with special databases. Later I would start an environment which might be my "data processing shell" that provides other shortcuts.

What's the best way to manage that?

cheers,
Achim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are quite a number of ways and “the best one” depends on many not explained factors. One not best but kind of straightforward way is the following.

Profiles are just scripts automatically dot-sourced in the global scope on start-up. In some sense we can call any script that is dot-sourced in the global scope later “a dynamic profile”. We can have several scripts that install global variables, functions, aliases and etc. with *the same* names but *different* values. In other words, we can have several scripts that install different “environments”. At any moment we take one and do:

```
. Set-Environment<SomeName>.ps1
```

and continue work with new environment `SomeName`. More or less, I use the approach like this in practice (exactly when working with databases, BTW).